# Build child on object parameter change

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a stateless `CharacterWidget` which contains children `HeadWidget`, `TorsoWidget`. For simplicity let's assume it has only `HeadWidget`. `HeadWidget` itself is a stateless widget with two children: `HelmetWidget` and `FaceWidget`. Here's what the tree looks like:

[image]

The `CharacterWidget` uses a `Provider` to give its children the CharacterObject - contains things like helmet type and skin complexity..

The question is: **When say `character.SkinComplexity` changes, I want the `FaceWidget` and `BodyWidget` to rebuild but not the `HelmetWidget` and `Chestplate`. Vice-versa if the `character.helmet` changes: I want ONLY the `HelmetWidget` to rebuild.** Currently, if I change `CharacterObject`, everything rebuild (based on logs in the build methods).

How can I tell a Widget to rebuild only if say `character.SkinComplexity` changes?

Side question: Am I correct to believe that all of these widgets should be Stateless if they're just displaying and applying a filter to an image?

Comment: How do you consume the provider? Do you use Provider.of(context) or context.watch()?

Comment: I use changeNotifierProvider on the parent and consume with Provider.of()..

Comment: Should I not be? @ddalbosco

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're searching for is the `Selector` widget and the `context.select()` function. They are pretty useful to optimize rebuilds, especially when using `ChangeNotifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Provider.of(context).property use context.watch().property. I had a similar problem to yours, I resolved by using this syntax, by making some tests I realized that using Provider.of() is like watching changes on all properties.